# Order of expression evaluation in C

Tags: c, c89

If I have the following expression:

```
c = (a) * (b)
```

What does the C90 standard say about the order evaluation of the subexpression 'a' and 'b'?

Comment: [Nothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspecified_behavior) :):):):)

Comment: Homework questions require a homework tag.

Comment: @Robert: I don't think anyone asks this in their homework...

Comment: @RobertHarvey A class that offers such questions for homework would be a nice class to attend: I cannot begin to imagine what the questions at the final exam would look like :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no specified order since the multiplication operator is not a sequence point. Sequence points include the comma operator, the end of a full expression, and function calls. Thus the order of evaluation of `(a)` and `(b)` is up to the compiler implementation.  Therefore you shouldn't attempt to-do something in `(a)` that would have a side-effect that you want to be seen in `(b)` in order to generate a valid result.

For instance:

```
int a=5;
int b = (a++) * (a++); //<== Don't do this!!
```

If you want a full-listing of sequence points for C, you can check out a [more thorough reference here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point).

Comment: Or, even better, a SO search.

Comment: Your example indeed shows incorrect code, but not due to evaluation order. Obviously, it's unimportant which `a++` is evaluated first.

Comment: Why would you say that?  Suppose you assumed that the first `a++` took place incrementing the value of `a` to 6 and returning 5, and then the second `a++` operation set `a` to a value of 7 and returned 6, thus providing a value of 30?  Of course if they went in the opposite order, then you would again get the value of 30, but the problem is you could have **any** ordering, not just the two I've described above.  For instance, a compiler may decide per the C99 spec to only modify the location of `a` once in the given expression, and thus you could end up with a return value of 25 or 36, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what "valid sequence point" means; there's no such thing as an "invalid sequence point".

Answer (score 3):

The evaluation order of the operands of the `*` binary operator is unspecified in C90.

Here is the relevant paragraph from the C90 Standard (as the question asked about C90):

> (C90, 6.3) "Except as indicated by the syntax or otherwise specified later (for the function-call operator (), &&, ||, ?:, and comma operators). the order of evaluation of subexpressions and the order in which side effects take place are both unspecitied"

For the `*` operator, if we take an example with side-effect operands like:

```
c =  f() * g();
```

the implementation can call `f()` first or `g()` first:

```
a = f();
b = g();
c = a * b;
```

or

```
a = g();
b = f();
c = a * b;
```

Both are valid translations.