# Does "(f(x))+g(y)" can make sure call f(x) first in C++?

Tags: c++, sequence-points

And does `f(x)+(g(y))` can make sure call `g(y)` first?
I know the order in expression is undefined in many case, but in this case does parentheses work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Order of expression evaluation in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437683/order-of-expression-evaluation-in-c)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9439459/2235132

Comment: If not close, can somebody at least quote the relevant parts of the standard from the links above.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Parentheses exist to override precedence. They have no effect on the order of evaluation.

Comment: I would like to add a reference here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Comment: @musefan No. The order in which operations are done has nothing to do with the order in which the parameters for those operations are themselves evaluated. If you compare `(a() + b()) + c()` to `a() + (b() + c())`, the parenthesis change the order of the additions, but you can still *evaluate* `a()`, `b()`, and `c()` in any order you want.

Comment: Talk about [lazy reputation day](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17485851/596781)... :-)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I wouldn't phrase it as "changes the order of the additions". It doesn't. I would phrase it as "changes *what* gets added to *what*". (a better example would use subtraction which is not associative)

Answer (score 12):

Look ma, two lines!

```
auto r = g(y);
f(x) + r;
```

This introduces the all-important [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) between the two function calls.  There may be other ways to do it, but this way seems straightforward and obvious.  Note that your parentheses do not introduce a sequence point, so aren't a solution.

Comment: This does not actually answer the question that was asked.

Comment: You were right, so I expanded a bit to explain and include a link (which funny enough, on Wikipedia shows this exact case as lacking a sequence point for C++).

Comment: Shouldn't this be `auto &&r = g(y);`? Otherwise you might introduce an additional copy, depending what type `g` returns.

Answer (score 2):

No. Unless the `+` operator is redefined, things like that are evaluated left to right. Even if you were able to influence the precedence in the operator, it wouldn't necessarily mean that `f` and `g` were evaluated in the same order. If you need `f` to be evaluated before `g`, you can always do:

```
auto resultOfF = f(x);
auto resultOfG = g(x);
resultOfF + resultOfG;
```

Comment: You're welcome. It's a C++11 feature, but a handy one at that, especially in exactly this case :)