# Why does PHP evaluate $b and $b = $b differently when used with $b++ in array index

Tags: php, operator-precedence

I am unable to grasp the evaluation logic in the code listed below. Does anyone know why PHP evaluates `$b` and `$b = $b` differently in this case?

I have read through a number of questions here at SO and checked the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). Doing so I've come to understand that *"PHP does not (in the general case) specify in which order an expression is evaluated"* and that *"the behavior can change between versions of PHP or depending on the surrounding code"*. I don't feel that that applies to this situation though. Or does it?

Being the first to admit this may not be your everyday coding issue, I am still curious. Stumbled upon it trying to do some [code golfing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

```
$a = [[00, 01, 02, 03],
      [10, 11, 12, 13],
      [20, 21, 22, 23],
      [30, 31, 32, 33]];

$b = 2;
echo $a[$b][$b++], PHP_EOL;

$b = 2;
echo $a[$b=$b][$b++], PHP_EOL;
```

Output - PHP 5.5.14:

```
32
22
```

Comment: What php is saying is that it doesn't guarantee order like mathematical order of operations. It might have the same order in every current version and system and work exactly the same. They are saying that a change in a later version might change the result and they won't guarantee it will always work the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This looks like the example in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) used for demonstrating **Undefined order of evaluation**.  From the manual:

> **Operator precedence and associativity only determine how expressions are grouped, they do not specify an order of evaluation.** PHP does not (in the general case) specify in which order an expression is evaluated and code that assumes a specific order of evaluation should be avoided, because the behavior can change between versions of PHP or depending on the surrounding code.

*Emphasis added*

The example they give:

```
<?php
$a = 1;
echo $a + $a++; // may print either 2 or 3

$i = 1;
$array[$i] = $i++; // may set either index 1 or 2
?>
```

You are getting the output you are because in the first example, the index `$b++` is being determined *first*, whereas in the second one the index `$b=$b` is first.

*NB*

As for *why* this is, I believe one possible reason is explained by this note on the same manual page:

> Although = has a lower precedence than most other operators, PHP will still allow expressions similar to the following: if (!$a = foo()), in which case the return value of foo() is put into $a.

I believe they're missing a crucial last word there: *first* (without, to me reading the note loses a bit of meaning).

Following PHP's own rules, *and* we assume a FIFO order, `!$a` should be evaluated first. If `$a` is currently `null` or `undefined`, then `!$a` will equal `true` (it will be evaluated and that result will be thrown away).  Following that, `foo()` will be evaluated, and its return value will be assigned to `$a` (even if we're assuming FIFO, `foo()` must be evaluated first if its result is to be assigned to something). The result of this assignment will be evaluated by `if`, and will result in exactly the opposite value that the author wanted.

I'm no C expert, but a bit of searching also lead me this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9439459/697370) which quotes the C90 Standard:

> (C90, 6.3) "Except as indicated by the syntax or otherwise specified later (for the function-call operator (), &&, ||, ?:, and comma operators). the order of evaluation of subexpressions and the order in which side effects take place are both unspecitied"

Since PHP is built on C, it makes sense that it would inherit some of its eccentricities.

Comment: So basically using `$b++` and `$b` on the same line is like the proverbial box of chocolates.

Comment: I thought maybe PHP saw `$b` and `$b = $b` as equivalent, like would have optimized the stupid assignment away, but I guess that is not the case then.